# sending values from command line?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

hai consider that my application name is sApp.exe

when i run my application as 
sApp.exe  < myValue> 
my application should start and i want to get that myValue in my application

how i can do this?

Comment: What language are you developing your application in?

Comment: am using c# in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: For WPF use `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`

For other applications(not WPF):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string argument in args)
       Console.WriteLine(argument);
}
```

If you want the first argument use `args[0]`, but be sure to check the length of the array before accessing it.

Comment: hai peter i just did wat u said.. but i can give my value with the exe ...
 i tried like sApp.exe myval but it doesnt get my value... how to give the values???

Comment: For the first real argument(not the sApp.exe) use args[1]. If you want the full line(which I doubt) use Environment.CommandLine.